# Apache: [error] child died with signal 7

Tags: apache

Помогите разобраться, апач ложится стабильно раз в сутки :( Но может и чаще. Никак не пойму, что это может вызывать. На VDS крутится 1 сайт. Может доходить до 100 онлайн. Но при этом апач живет и крутится как надо. Ночью когда нет нагрузки, что-то его крушит. 
В логах вот такая информация.

```
[Sun Feb 21 03:21:01 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Feb 21 03:21:01 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Feb 21 03:21:01 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 21 03:21:19 2016] [error] child died with signal 7
[Sun Feb 21 03:23:21 2016] [error] child died with signal 7
[Sun Feb 21 03:23:49 2016] [error] child died with signal 11
[Sun Feb 21 03:23:50 2016] [error] child died with signal 11
[Sun Feb 21 03:23:50 2016] [error] child died with signal 11
[Sun Feb 21 03:23:51 2016] [error] child died with signal 11
...... Еще 20 таких died
[Sun Feb 21 04:19:50 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Feb 21 04:19:51 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Feb 21 04:19:51 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Feb 21 04:19:51 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
```

php -v

```
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Feb  9 2016 10:36:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with XCache v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
with XCache Cacher v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
```

На сайте стоит модуль определения по IP через сервис ipgeobase.ru
Сразу после рестарта Апача вываливается вот такой error:

```
[Sun Feb 21 09:05:15 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Feb 21 09:05:16 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Feb 21 09:05:16 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Feb 21 09:05:16 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
About to connect() to ipgeobase.ru port 7020 (#0)
Trying 194.85.91.253... * connected
Connected to ipgeobase.ru (194.85.91.253) port 7020 (#0)
GET /geo/?ip=204.79.180.26 HTTP/1.1
Host: ipgeobase.ru:7020
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.15
Date: Sun, 21 Feb 2016 06:08:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 130

Connection #0 to host ipgeobase.ru left intact
Closing connection #0
```

Answer (score 1):

Для потомков:
Причина была в Xcache. Отключил его и проблема исчезла.